# Ansible looping over nested tasks

Tags: ansible

Is there any way call one task from another, loop through some array and pass variable to this other task?

```
- include: { task: create_user.yml user: item }
  with_items: users
```

or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can just assume that "user" is available to creater_user.yml

```
# something like this: 
- name: create user
  include creater_user.yml


# creater_user.yml:
- name: some task
  debug: msg="hello"
  with_items: users
```

Comment: That's not really the same as the OP wanted... since you have to repeat the "with_items" for each task in create_user.yml and that has different semantics to looping over 2+ tasks for each item (some task 1 for item, then some task 2 for item, then some task 1 for item 2, etc) if the include accepted with_items. AFAIK what the OP wants cannot be done :-( I'd love to hear otherwise though.

Comment: @richq, I suppose it's not the same as what the OP wanted but it does offer comparable (albeit syntactically redundant) results. Given that what the OP asked for didn't seem possible, I offered this here as a potential solution.